# RegisterPowerSettingNotification use in Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

How to use the [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196.aspx) in conjuction with [GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448380.aspx) in Delphi XE2?

Comment: for example like this: http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=314202  But what is your actual problem?  http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Comment: @Arioch, you don't need to have a problem if you want to be notified by the [`GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448380.aspx#GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON) notification. Raw N, yet another example you can [`find here`](http://pastebin.com/Evs5D0pN). Since you're using Delphi XE2, you won't need the prototype definitions. I'm having just Delphi 2009 by hand. And, I can't test it since I don't know how to turn off a monitor on my laptop :-)

Comment: @TLama Usually you don't query some state from the OS and go lengths to implement callback boilerplate just to discard the result. It usually is done to make some decision. And the link above, read it, immediately asks about the goal. It looks liek usually this callback is (ab)used to "cause child vomit after he ate poison" INSTEAD OF "prevent him eating poison" /// Notebook: Usually that is done using Fn+some-key combo listed in manuals. But are you sure Windows would be necessarily informed of lamp power cut-off ? If i'd wish to test it, i'd launched the stock Windows display-off screensaver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the desired GUID [Power Setting GUIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to registers the application to receive power setting notifications for a specific power setting event, if not needed anymore the call [UnregisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A delphi example could look like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

const
  GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON: TGUID = '{02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea}';

type

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FHPOWERNOTIFY: THandle;
  protected
    procedure WM_POWERBROADCAST(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_POWERBROADCAST;
  end;

function RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hRecipient: THandle;
  PowerSettingGuid: PGUID; Flags: DWORD): THandle; stdcall;
external 'user32.dll';
function UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(Handle: THandle): BOOL; stdcall;
external 'user32.dll';

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FHPOWERNOTIFY := RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Handle,
    @GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(FHPOWERNOTIFY);
end;

procedure TForm1.WM_POWERBROADCAST(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if PPOWERBROADCAST_SETTING(Msg.LParam)^.Data[0] = 0 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Off')
  else
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ON')
end;

end.
```

Comment: @TLama I saw your example. The code in Bummi's answer seems to be working just fine. Maybe his answer needs to be updated for PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE?

Comment: Yes. You need to check, which event caused the `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message to be send and then if it was `PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE` also check, which power notification caused that event (this is important if you were having registered more than the `GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON` notification). But if this code is enough for you, then I wish you good luck! ;-) Just a sidenote, the `HPOWERNOTIFY` is defined as `PVOID` in WinUser.h header file.

Comment: Very usefull answer, not only did you solve my problem. you also shed some light on how to get windows information that is not in the standard delphi winapi. thanks!

Comment: I am trying this in Delphi 7?   Which Delphi unit is  PPOWERBROADCAST_SETTING. I could not compile