# How to use RegisterPowerSettingNotification

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I want to be notified when my computer power source changes.

So first I 've created a simple Delphi application and listening for 
`WM_POWERBROADCAST` at the main form.

**WM_POWERBROADCAST**

```
type
  TForm38 = class(TForm)
  public
    procedure WM_POWERBROADCAST(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_POWERBROADCAST;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm38.WM_POWERBROADCAST(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  Caption := Msg.LParam.ToString;
end;
```

Then I got my notifications, but  `Msg.LParam` is allways 0 (zero)

Then I've tried to call [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196(v=vs.85).aspx) and found an example in this old [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911664/registerpowersettingnotification-use-in-delphi), but I still have the same problem: `Msg.LParam` is allways 0 (zero)

**RegisterPowerSettingNotification**

```
type
  TForm38 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FHPOWERNOTIFY: HPOWERNOTIFY;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure WM_POWERBROADCAST(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_POWERBROADCAST;
  end;

implementation

const
  GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE: TGUID = '{5D3E9A59-E9D5-4B00-A6BD-FF34FF516548}';

procedure TForm38.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FHPOWERNOTIFY := RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Handle, GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
end;

procedure TForm38.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(FHPOWERNOTIFY);
end;

procedure TForm38.WM_POWERBROADCAST(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  Caption := Msg.LParam.ToString;
end;
```

The application run on Windows 10.

What am I doing wrong?

**THE RESULT**

Using the code from the answer to this question, I've ended up writing this class:

```
unit PowerWatcherU;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, System.SyncObjs, Winapi.Messages;

{$M+}

type
  TPowerSource = (PoAc = 0, PoDc = 1, PoHot = 2);
  TPowerSourceChanged = procedure(const PowerSource: TPowerSource) of object;

  TPowerWatcher = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyHWND: HWND;
    FHPOWERNOTIFY: HPOWERNOTIFY;
    FOnPowerSourceChanged: TPowerSourceChanged;
    procedure DoPowerSourceChanged(const Value: TPowerSource);
    procedure WndHandler(var Msg: TMessage);
    procedure SetOnPowerSourceChanged(const Value: TPowerSourceChanged);
  published
    property OnPowerSourceChanged: TPowerSourceChanged read FOnPowerSourceChanged write SetOnPowerSourceChanged;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

const
  GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE: TGUID = '{5D3E9A59-E9D5-4B00-A6BD-FF34FF516548}';

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils;

{ TPowerWatcher }

constructor TPowerWatcher.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FMyHWND := AllocateHWND(WndHandler);
  FHPOWERNOTIFY := RegisterPowerSettingNotification(FMyHWND, GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
end;

destructor TPowerWatcher.Destroy;
begin
  DeallocateHWND(FMyHWND);
  UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(FHPOWERNOTIFY);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPowerWatcher.DoPowerSourceChanged(const Value: TPowerSource);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnPowerSourceChanged) then
    FOnPowerSourceChanged(Value);
end;

procedure TPowerWatcher.SetOnPowerSourceChanged(const Value: TPowerSourceChanged);
begin
  FOnPowerSourceChanged := Value;
end;

procedure TPowerWatcher.WndHandler(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_POWERBROADCAST) and (Msg.WParam = PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE) then
  begin
    if PPowerBroadcastSetting(Msg.LParam)^.PowerSetting = GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE then
      DoPowerSourceChanged(TPowerSource(PPowerBroadcastSetting(Msg.LParam)^.Data[0]));
  end
  else
    Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FMyHWND, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Two obvious mistakes. Using Handle and so risking window recreation. And you'll just get the latest message. You might miss intermediate messages. Go the extra mile and log the values you get.

Comment: Ok this was just a quick and dirty example made for testing. In my real code I use AllocateHWnd inorder to har "my own handle"

Comment: About logging then Wparam is allways 10 and is Lparam allways 0

Comment: It's really no fun when askers show code, but when we comment on the code that was shown, the asker says, "oh no, the actual code is different."

Comment: It makes no diffrence. Since this is just a demo application, I start it up and remove the power form my computer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan would you please point to a reference on an alternative to the Form's Window Handle?

Comment: @GabrielF create your own handle: AllocateHWnd(WndMethod); where is a TWndMethod

Comment: @GabrielF Jens is right. You really need to supply a window handle whose lifetime you control. And AllocateHWnd is the canonical way to do so.

Comment: Fwiw, there was a thread in the EMBA NGs about this last year started by Roy Lambert, while their server was up and down like the proverbial..  At the moment, the only fragment I can find is this:https://newsgroups.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=107651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you are suffering from window re-creation.  Your code as posted works fine for me but this may not be the case in Win10.  With that aside, the only other oddity is that you are duplicating an identifier by naming a method `WM_POWERBROADCAST`, although this should not cause the code to break.  Working example using a dedicated `HWND` :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Forms, StdCtrls, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Messages;

type

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    private
      FMyHWND : HWND;
      FHPowerNotify: HPOWERNOTIFY;
    public
      procedure WndHandler(var Msg: TMessage);
 end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

const
  GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE: TGUID = '{5D3E9A59-E9D5-4B00-A6BD-FF34FF516548}';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyHWND := AllocateHWND(WndHandler);
  FHPowerNotify := RegisterPowerSettingNotification(FMyHWND,
                                                    GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, 
                                                    DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(FHPowerNotify);
  DeallocateHWND(FMyHWND);
end;

procedure TForm1.WndHandler(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_POWERBROADCAST) and
     (Msg.WParam = PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE) then
  begin
    if PPowerBroadcastSetting(Msg.LParam)^.PowerSetting = GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE then
      case cardinal(PPowerBroadcastSetting(Msg.LParam)^.Data[0]) of
        0: Caption := 'AC Power';
        1: Caption := 'DC Power';
        2: Caption := 'HOT - UPS, etc';
      end;
  end else
    msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FMyHWND, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is not the case.Because I just strars my application, nad the removed the power form the computer.

If I use AllocateHWND my computer breaks down  when I remove the power.

Comment: Breaksdown meaning: Freezes and then turns off.

Comment: This question have become a mess. I'll just close it, and create a new one when I have narrowed the problem

Comment: So, are you saying that your AllocateHWND *causes* the freeze/turn off or what?

Comment: @MartynA  freeze/turn off the computer. But now I just started a new project and copied the above code into it and that works.

Comment: Istr somewhere, it might have been Roy's thread I mentioned, or another, where it turned out that there was a Windows configuration setting that was related to waking Windows up to do process power-message handling when the machine is nominally "sleeping"

Comment: @JensBorrisholt If your machine turns off when you unplug the power, are you sure it has a battery? ;)